# How to check WFS error

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I'm adding a layer to an OpenLayers Map which includes data from GeoServer retrieved using WFS. The layer is created like following:

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:26713"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: "http://localhost/geodemo/geoserver/wfs",
        featureType: "LayerName",
        srsName: "EPSG:26713",
            featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/MyNS",
        geometryName: "the_geom",
                            })
});
```

When sending WFS messages to GeoServer, the server could send errors (formatated as XML). How it is possible to be aware from these errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can regist in events from Save Strategy:

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Save-js.html

```
saveStrategy.events.register("fail", saveStrategy, function () {
    alert('fail');
});

saveStrategy.events.register("success", saveStrategy, function () {
    alert('success');
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In **firefox**, you can add the firebug plugin to inspect the incoming and outgoing request..

In **chrome**, you can use inspect element (you will have to enable **Log XMLHttpRequests** from settings)

Comment: Yes, but i need to handle this errors to show them as a message to final user...

Comment: OpenLayers.Request which performs the ajax requests supports success and failure mode for request.

Answer (score 0):

Check for ExceptionReport in the XML response.

http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/198

Comment: please do not use short link only answers. explanation of what the link fixes and why it is an answer are required.